# How to sum variables in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm new in XSLT, and I'm having problems to solve this. I have some values that aren't in the XML document, so I need to create them, like this:

```
   <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($obsData)/Round">
    <xsl:with-param name="Save1">
       <xsl:variable name="xx">
        <xsl:element name="lasuma">
         <xsl:value-of select="(some calculation)"/>
        </xsl:element>
       </xsl:variable>  
       <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($xx)/lasuma"/> 
    </xsl:with-param>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

So now that I have the values that I need, I save them into the variable. Now I need to sum it, but the only way that the function SUM seems to works is when you have nodes, and I can't sum the values in a variable. I tried this, but it doesn't sum the values that I specified in that path:

..."sum(msxsl:node-set($xx)/lasuma)"/>

Is there a way to sum the values in a variable? A simple example that I might follow, would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example - see:[mcve].

Answer (score 3):

if you want to sum any variable you have to say that variable is a number.

So in XSLT you can use number(value)+number(otherValue)

Comment: And how can I set the entire variable to a number? Instead of one by one. The data came from loops, so I can't do it one by one.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You dont need to actually.Because you only need to change the value when you want to sum.the value is actually stored in both string and number but only you  have to mention about it when you want to make mathematical operations.I hope i could explain it.

Comment: <xsl:when test="$par/w:pPr/w:numPr/w:ilvl/@w:val > number($levelPrevious)+1"> is the basic example of how i use this in loops.Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Just make sure your calculation creates a valid number.  If not, you will get NaN, "not a number", returned from your sum.

```
<xsl:variable name="xx">
  <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($obsData)/Round">
    <xsl:element name="lasuma">
     <xsl:value-of select="(some calculation)"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="sum(msxsl:node-set($xx)/lasuma)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, your help was very useful.